# How to get Method-Meta information within a Method Attribute?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

How to get Method-Meta information within a Method Attribute ?

I wont to avoid having to write the Event-Name both in the **attribute** and in the **parameters** of the method.

For the name of one property, the **nameof(Type)** can be acceptable, but for other cross-cutting-concerns, its simple not enough.

There are a lot of cross-cutting-concerns that need this - this is just one example:

```cs
 // From
        [SubscribeToEvent(nameof(SomeEventType))]
        public async Task SomeEventTypeEndpoint(SomeEventType someEvent)
        { (...) }
 // To
        [SubscribeToEvent]
        public async Task SomeEventTypeEndpoint(SomeEventType someEvent)
        { (...) }
```

```cs
// From
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class SubscribeToEventAttribute : TopicAttribute
    {
        public SubscribeToEventAttribute(string eventName) 
        {
           // Do: log name, analytics, ect...
        }
    }
// To
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class SubscribeToEventAttribute : TopicAttribute
    {
        public SubscribeToEventAttribute() 
        {
           // Some reflection on what this attribute is applied to ?
           // Getting something like System.Reflection.ParameterInfo
           // Do: log name, analytics, ect...
        }
    }
```

Some people

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this inside an attribute constructor. You will need to use reflection to find methods that define the attribute.

So to find all methods in a class that define an attribute, say `SubscribeToEventAttribute`, on a class, you can do something like this:

```cs
public static void CheckForSubscribeToEventAttributes(Type type) {
    var methods = type.GetMethods();
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.Length; i++) {
        MethodInfo method = methods[i];
        if (method.IsDefined(typeof(SubscribeToEventAttribute))) {
            // Do something with the method ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to get the actual attribute instances (and not just check if an attribute exists) you can use [`MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes?view=net-5.0#System_Reflection_MemberInfo_GetCustomAttributes_System_Type_System_Boolean_). In fact, attribute constructors are not run until you call this method.